# When using Class.getResource() and ClassLoader.getResource()

Tags: java

I just learned the way to get resource from Java and see that we can use `getResource()` to get a resource by two ways.

```
Class.getResource()

ClassLoader.getResource()
```

I confuse when we will use `Class.getResource()` and when we will use `ClassLoader.getResource()`.

Does anyone have some words on that?

Comment: Thank you but seems the reference discussed the difference in usage. Not mention what situation we should use Class.getResource() and ClassLoader.getResource()

Comment: One should avoid  `getClass().getResource(relativePath)` in favor of `MyClass.getResource` as classes can be overriden, invaldating the relative path. There is no real difference so Class#getResource is shorter. And note that ClassLoader has only absolute paths without starting /.

Answer (score 2):

It is always a `ClassLoader` that ends up doing the work that finds a resource and makes it available to your code.  But you don't immediately have access to a `ClassLoader` instance necessarily.  If you do, and you know that's the right `ClassLoader` to use, then you should go ahead and use it directly by calling the `getResource()` method on it.

Using `<Class instance>.getResource()` is usually a more direct and "smarter" way to get the behavior you want.  It does a number of different things to determine the correct `ClassLoader` to use to do the lookup.  Then it ends up calling `<ClassLoader instance>.getResource()` or one of its cousin methods (like `ClassLoader.getSystemResource()`) to do the lookup of the resource.  Since you always have access to A class, and you usually have access to THE class with which a resource is associated, it's more convenient to call `<Class instance>.getResource()` and let the system do the work of finding the appropriate `ClassLoader` to use.

NOTE: In cases not involving modules, `<Class instance>.getResource()` is often equivalent to `<Class instance>.getClassLoader().getResource()`. But not all classes have an associated `ClassLoader`.  Calling the `Class` version of `getResource()` will use the system `ClassLoader` if the class itself does not have an associated `ClassLoader`.